# How do I get raw request body using servicestack with content-type set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: request, servicestack

I have my DTO

```
Route("/testing","POST")]
public class TestingRequest:IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

and my service

```
public async Task<object> Post(TestingRequest req)
{
    var rawbody = base.Request.GetRawBody();
    var data = req.RequestStream.ReadFully();
    var strdata = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    ...
}
```

And I found that when calling it, rawbody or data is not empty only if content-type is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded. If the content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, rawbody and data will be empty.

How do I get the raw request body as a whole (string) when the caller set the content-type to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

My current env is ubuntu 16.04 with dotnet core 1.1, don't know if it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack uses a forward only request stream that unless you tell ServiceStack to buffer the Request Stream with a pre-request filter:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) => {
    httpReq.UseBufferedStream = true;
});
```

Either ServiceStack reads or you can read by having your Request DTOs implement `IRequiresRequestStream` to tell ServiceStack to skip reading the Request Body and that you're going to in your Services.

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests are special in that if `IRequest.FormData` is accessed it will trigger reading the Request Body. You can tell ServiceStack to skip reading the FormData when it creates the Request with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    SkipFormDataInCreatingRequest = true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just double checking, are you saying that, even with  the IRequiresRequestStream (as you can see from my question post that my DTO is properly implemented, or haven't I), I still need to set the SkipFormDataInCreatingRequest ? Because application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests are special. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @shawhu for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests you need to tell ServiceStack not to check `Request.FormData` for param overrides when creating the Request DTO as it will trigger reading the body.